# How To Make Text Move back and Forth On a Curved Path HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, text

I'm trying to make the text "sample text sample text" move back and forth on a curved path. As you can see in the snippet I have been able to get in to move back and forth in a straight line but I don't know how to curve it and make it follow along that curved path. Also if someone could help me speed up the "ease" when the text gets to the ends of the path that would be nice.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>




    <style>
        *{
            margin: 0rem;
            padding: 0rem;
            box-sizing: border-box; 
        }
        html {
            font-size: 62.5%;
        }

        body {
            background: #1B2A41;
        }

        .container {
            margin: auto;
            width:  20rem;
            background-color: transparent;
        }

        .path {
            position: absolute;
            overflow: hidden;
            top: 15rem;
            left: 15rem;
            width: 165rem;
            height: 40rem;
            background-color: none;
            margin: auto;
            transform: rotate(20deg);
        }

        .shape {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            background-color: none;
            height: 12rem;
            display: block;
            top: 40%;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 5rem;
            font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
            color: #c4def5;
            text-shadow: 0 0 20px #4e91ac;
            
            
            x-transition: all 1s ;
            animation: ani 10s infinite;
        }

        .shape:after {
            content: attr(data-text);
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            padding: 0 20px;
            z-index: -1;
            color: #8db9e0;
            filter: blur(15px);
        }


        @keyframes ani {
        0% {
            left: 0rem;
        }
        50% {
            left: 50rem;
        }
        100% {
            left: 0rem;
        }
        }

     
    </style>



    <script>
        console.log('hello world')

        //#8db9e0
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="path">
            <span id="elem" class="shape trail"><h1 data-text='[sample text sample text]'>sample text sample text</h1></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Searched around a bit a found this link: https://tobiasahlin.com/blog/curved-path-animations-in-css/. Is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: You can get part way using keyframes and layers but could end up animating each character separately as keyframes essentially move things in straight lines. SVG animation along a path may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to find a way of animating text along a path using CSS only.

Using SVG it is possible to write text along a path and then animate it by changing the startOffset attribute. startOffset says how far along the path the text should start. For example, this article [https://css-tricks.com/moving-text-on-a-curved-path](https://css-tricks.com/moving-text-on-a-curved-path/)/ changes the attribute using Javascript.

Seeking a non-JS solution, it does not seem possible to animate such text using CSS but we can use SVG's own animate functionality. This snippet takes the path used in the CSS-tricks article but adds animate tags which move the text along the path in one direction, then reverse the movement and each repeats on the other finishing. CSS is used to rotate the containing div.

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
div {
  transform: rotate(20deg);
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  top:40%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
svg {
  font-size:50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg width="100%" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 1098.72 89.55">
    <path id="curve" fill="transparent" d="M0.17,0.23c0,0,105.85,77.7,276.46,73.2s243.8-61.37,408.77-54.05c172.09,7.64,213.4,92.34,413.28,64.19"></path>
    <text width="100%" style="transform:translate3d(0,0,0);">
        <textPath id="text-path" style="transform:translate3d(0,0,0);" alignment-baseline="top" xlink:href="#curve"> 
               sample text sample text
             <animate id="anim1" attributeName="startOffset"
               from="0" to="600"
               begin="0s;anim2.end" dur="5s"
               repeatCount="1"
             />
             <animate id="anim2" attributeName="startOffset"
                from="600" to ="0"
                begin="anim1.end" dur="5s"
                repeatCount="1"
             />
         </textPath>
    </text>
  </svg>
</div>
```